# Is there any way to use continue on a loop that im not in?

Tags: python, for-loop, break, continue

```
for i in range(10):
   for j in range(10):
      if somecondition:
          continue
```

--> here I want to continue the loop with `for i in range(10)`, not the `j` loop. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `break` to exit the nested loop. For example

```
for i in range(10):
   for j in range(10):
      if somecondition:
          break
```

Comment: Assuming there is nothing after the inner loop, such as in this particular case.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks for the comment, you are right. Otherwise the OP has to provide more context.